bootstrap for model estimation with a created function
I am trying to make comparisons between treatments of my heritability estimates, values ​​that I calculated with the following function:
data <- 
  data.frame(treatment=c("control", "ivermectin", "pla2guicide", "parasitism"),
             temperature=c("29", "33"), pronotum=c(4.12, 4.21, 4.33, 4.26, 4.34, 
                                                   4.21, 4.52, 4.35))
data

her_pro <- function(data, indices) {
  mod <- lmer(pronotum ~ 1 + (1 | terrarium), data = data[indices, ])
  df <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(mod))
  family <- df[1, 4]
  residual <- df[2, 4]
  heritability <- family/(family + residual)
  return(heritability)
}

I used that function to obtain a heritability index, from a mixed model. Then I made a Bootstrap as follows:
BC29_p <- boot(data=data, statistic=her_pro, R=100)

Now, I want to know if that value of heritability is statistically different between treatments.
What test can I do to compare heritability values?
I've been trying with the finalfit library and the boot_predict function, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right?

There is no terrarium in your data set.

You seem to be trying to do a non-parametric bootstrap, i.e. a resampling rows with replacement, which may not be the best idea with mixed models because the terrarium clusters will be of different sizes in each replication. Better do a parametric bootstrap which simulates pronotum outcomes by repeatedly adding residuals drawn from a normal distribution with the parameters from the model (mean, SD) to the fitted values y_hat. Check whether the residuals of your model are approximately normally distributed first.
> library(lme4)
> MMfit <- lmer(pronotum ~ 1 + temperature + (1 | terrarium), data=data)
> resid(MMfit) |> summary()
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-0.308875 -0.089320 -0.005235  0.000000  0.076235  0.340211 


> hist(resid(MMfit), 'fd')


> resid(MMfit) |> shapiro.test()

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  resid(MMfit)
W = 0.99026, p-value = 0.009482

In the Shapiro test, focus on W if W >= 0.9 (i.e. close to 1) or at least p > 0.0001, which looks good in this case.
lme4 has a bootMer() function which does a parametric bootstrap, you won't need the boot package.
> her_pro <- function(mod) {
+   var_comp <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(mod))
+   family <- var_comp$vcov[var_comp$grp == "terrarium"]
+   residual <- var_comp$vcov[var_comp$grp == "Residual"]
+   heritability <- family/(family + residual)
+   return(heritability)
+ }
> boo01 <- 
+   bootMer(MMfit, her_pro, nsim=5e3, seed=42, parallel='multicore', ncpus=7L)
> boo01

PARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
bootMer(x = MMfit, FUN = her_pro, nsim = 5000, seed = 42, parallel = "multicore", 
    ncpus = 7)


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original        bias    std. error
t1* 0.06467749 -0.0001821324  0.04021775

112 message(s): boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

> confint(boo01)
            2.5 %  97.5 %
[1,] 0.0008393493 0.15477

If you want to know whether you are calculating the heritability statistics correctly, you'd better ask on Cross Validated.

Data:
> dput(data)
structure(list(treatment = c("control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", "ivermectin", 
"ivermectin", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", "pla2guicide", 
"pla2guicide", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", "parasitism", 
"parasitism"), temperature = c(29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33), pronotum = c(4.14027463438795, 
4.17330445009485, 4.35219303045809, 4.20337303818563, 4.20925097255927, 
4.3678286977315, 4.2424138196421, 4.06981607558252, 4.12763691385382, 
4.15175600203318, 4.26397560852273, 4.17754881148452, 4.18164457383819, 
4.15263570037329, 4.08598331530338, 4.32025874245909, 4.19135247660171, 
3.94490571311582, 4.21170301893515, 4.09428828800599, 4.06148021615587, 
4.14646509528873, 4.06566214192383, 4.09537346382544, 4.10575865996963, 
3.99959325568031, 4.25204129120401, 4.18359989853821, 4.05444889305336, 
4.29364407886155, 4.24120434450127, 4.16905077405436, 4.28807048845809, 
4.28637127110689, 4.28071603051733, 4.26742194776359, 4.25394968770734, 
4.19236675129591, 4.16796165597959, 4.16051082225235, 4.16406410054465, 
4.21274307063474, 4.10699516327987, 4.45043039497055, 4.3543309982672, 
4.12122394011636, 4.19324631490679, 4.18686926307438, 4.31153131027033, 
4.22519789178951, 4.14280452422822, 4.11461799729388, 4.11318562709961, 
4.25433290123019, 4.09489557426282, 4.2691197332717, 3.96259739240572, 
4.17593404779235, 4.12985809721321, 4.13906682970314, 4.22047623631542, 
4.13227994272851, 4.1491915496725, 4.08065474972873, 4.07533316539188, 
4.21286515217986, 4.22733326590238, 4.18781271071249, 4.27473903482741, 
4.38752075660215, 4.18871720532162, 4.00690343436319, 4.3383941743735, 
4.16690024566904, 4.16901946028054, 4.34037745889694, 4.20934302122217, 
4.11574855070182, 4.25595066990219, 4.22393118568337, 4.17363596059111, 
4.21158758211375, 4.13599353882188, 4.237497196853, 4.15101088581925, 
4.20623773839269, 4.28274344331606, 4.2165776910845, 4.140466383448, 
4.28794030384623, 4.31071498167986, 4.26620429203445, 4.23523776959479, 
4.14857398847971, 4.34742984093665, 4.15133863736893, 4.4300978953853, 
4.36462565870217, 4.1877945601736, 4.10872250605297, 4.22528154267325, 
4.32201056995883, 4.27165301119694, 4.2615679391034, 4.20116034231667, 
4.29181942656228, 4.21783175209747, 4.12952800538436, 4.2582995470144, 
4.38822185994925, 4.18403273251794, 4.30236386100129, 4.07977915794987, 
4.23601123222633, 4.29350814917313, 4.27168276499545, 4.25213504819368, 
4.17749682794824, 4.15659699417542, 4.13915454971829, 4.28002724646457, 
4.17351512533607, 4.21920684238449, 4.24265336753473, 4.45264878727778, 
4.20306759658501, 4.29180124398304, 4.27605867171093, 4.17207692334154, 
4.26113177814219, 4.44301300819592, 4.34370832766151, 4.30268121455288, 
4.25630823911962, 4.09323320019953, 4.411691643695, 4.1524939152611, 
4.37255267344132, 4.48946827927533, 4.1541686062564, 4.40371323197417, 
4.30731504949645, 4.17632038252215, 4.18206803305852, 4.17338118107924, 
4.28044414621967, 4.18735923993711, 4.40232647573428, 4.54354569248926, 
4.20483175083318, 4.29624655757626, 4.29437689692884, 4.25069293072376, 
4.11663501200104, 4.20552741216568, 4.18943313931172, 4.27377162615079, 
4.18022879721836, 4.31517001149731, 4.18001458705204, 4.38778343459737, 
4.17759458737283, 4.15649676356363, 4.60661628153368, 4.24082652922339, 
4.31233504719351, 4.34616925544282, 4.23413422546856, 4.3341984924708, 
4.31940874077794, 4.3162822711631, 4.34434962527981, 4.33441359655343, 
4.55066551182889, 4.26368671229999, 4.22822069521981, 4.34159916184438, 
4.36886839687159, 4.38147266981829, 4.29198378865616, 4.166726928604, 
4.39937805961007, 4.23809450320577, 4.18650825573578, 4.24943158510701, 
4.25334195256626, 4.38405157097248, 4.28153327122084, 4.34846492051957, 
4.22313034028389, 4.33280912704181, 4.27889600493456, 4.320822948901, 
4.22182826028589, 4.18028444275085, 4.51108593455844, 4.37143547845089, 
4.18623745992115, 4.2502480044156, 4.19281658762392, 4.61620323393155, 
4.52756349668653, 4.36980769337354, 4.45064160496639, 4.35488820425129, 
4.34869750958162, 4.31746191525815, 4.33686047229723, 4.56141294577685, 
4.39091938653463, 4.35349195242154, 4.36593617173869, 4.46481501662732, 
4.2899610456843, 4.24231671373958, 4.5091371220191, 4.29745110708825, 
4.26926083178479, 4.21794011689045, 4.213095856547, 4.31086523882476, 
4.43006116847121, 4.47924740064753, 4.43902142213811, 4.33189685704503, 
4.37423758049301, 4.29780294038655, 4.29654077059715, 4.45672763665225, 
4.2667033288942, 4.59408731890283, 4.389525962957, 4.42001180501651, 
4.32470515187963, 4.34111905337726, 4.26685630912306, 4.38026538351631, 
4.44045616284603, 4.43098835676972, 4.32040427364811, 4.3546726013513, 
4.38331492660241, 4.58314086542133, 4.31980443637012, 4.41562963899868, 
4.62377098060459, 4.42343730990382, 4.29755072805456, 4.36705785490929, 
4.48208079632718, 4.27991238566177, 4.26128503647377, 4.2830809494159, 
4.32652233754267, 4.47732354994333, 4.30861616161486, 4.4255526224439, 
4.3805480843938, 4.30610868327813, 4.16418247253968, 4.33040055628418, 
4.33352524272559, 4.38722773131559, 4.51253215580612, 4.61182018542255, 
4.53727039393781, 4.36919719160654, 4.20685954848367, 4.34363430163226, 
4.39143301034677, 4.52232162233402, 4.5340731187757, 4.50625126486892, 
4.29829288694733, 4.52278462649061, 4.39316460028455, 4.4553005919434, 
4.44527543964465, 4.48063699842433, 4.44028782020989, 4.20631203224255, 
4.44670913847847, 4.41166219883609, 4.3464943794733, 4.38487399310579, 
4.38646340653797, 4.39516148885722, 4.53714415859887, 4.35115450410777, 
4.38986608038959, 4.52820298339056, 4.51678269842134, 4.52589090712168, 
4.35361779597769, 4.61161286911293, 4.41803468317667, 4.59804978055433, 
4.27627432748058, 4.41346295471907, 4.53635605318057, 4.1747979803209, 
4.1710533022214, 4.15246832868249, 4.1410708711093, 4.20260624572514, 
4.27944011633907, 4.0449011492511, 4.2675202423804, 4.36998970368483, 
4.45007960086722, 4.32168502799884, 4.26724490515838, 4.01889438886735, 
4.1314167579781, 4.15636278312052, 4.26191981905447, 4.1810002953784, 
4.06570256597277, 4.36001099958819, 4.28270655795838, 4.24200561400366, 
4.34007344778714, 4.08438515803106, 4.28434461653353, 4.16597134912321, 
4.28663713893963, 4.21218039128855, 4.2815586580577, 4.35181434826049, 
4.21899159578624, 4.35031378604879, 4.12971451883879, 4.17639747830998, 
4.4004796934924, 4.28629671965598, 4.04333564031021, 4.11215417714535, 
4.22847982079467, 4.33513586278703, 4.23836959678206, 4.34595354563876, 
4.37943533621548, 4.45064028132299, 4.28913647176419, 4.27833660781861, 
4.10821106252247, 4.29346755784548, 4.22634979264714, 4.18613384015629, 
4.26554417533194, 4.26896699010311, 3.96819782395989, 4.1247447441082, 
4.17913640118702, 4.07815191582325, 4.20086296707867, 4.20861566489032, 
4.16416905690115, 3.92088285345274, 4.42461848741541, 4.21198236229262, 
4.2976316161982, 4.25988893714309, 4.33497961152127, 4.31427823267685, 
4.21153297091659, 4.27032906526029, 4.13797140492705, 4.31820458912937, 
4.186408454151, 4.52949765730609, 4.12271543235846, 4.24142159763067, 
4.3703583082032, 4.33883357661514, 4.22887221807577, 4.18814224770652, 
4.30226789239834, 4.28638958061058, 4.10879219820087, 4.22651464871451, 
4.24208257357037, 4.2405321816993, 4.11755783774085, 4.27067286983138, 
4.36091655569704, 4.2686831823191, 4.10950069496369, 4.17949499503193, 
4.25766990395648, 4.19666003295182, 4.04559996258212, 4.34978967808647, 
4.17841683492119, 4.20400856900682, 4.4117546569841, 4.18395010312311, 
4.34593775010258, 4.13529630820177, 4.22591035577625), terrarium = c("a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", 
"f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", 
"h", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "j", "j", 
"j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
"e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", 
"f", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "i", "i", "i", 
"i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", 
"j", "j", "j", "j", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
"e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "h", "h", "h", "h", 
"h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", 
"i", "i", "i", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", 
"f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", 
"h", "h", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "j", 
"j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-400L))

